# tweepy not giving result when using time parameters

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get data between two dates but when I use max_id it is not giving me any results. does someone have any solution to this.

my code

```
    date1 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)
    date1 = date1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    date2 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)
    date2 = date2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    # get tweets
    for item in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=hashtag, since_id=date1, max_id=date2,   tweet_mode='extended', lang="en", result_type='popular').items():

        print([item.full_text,
               item.created_at,
               item.retweet_count,
               item.favorite_count,
               item.user.followers_count,
               item.user.profile_image_url,
               item.entities['hashtags']])
```

when I don't use max_id it works but then also the data is not of the correct timespan

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Tweepy docs:

"Twitter’s standard search API only “searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.”

If you’re specifying an ID range beyond the past 7 days or there are no results from the past 7 days, then no results will be returned."

A search into the last 90 days would require you to have access to the Premium API with elevated/Academic research access, which allows the **search_full_archive** command.